On click event does not fire
I have a simple on click method which works as native html onclick=changeImage(123)
but doesn't fire as @click=changeImage(123) or using v-on:click.
I have to use the Vue syntax because I want to send variables to the method body like
@click=changeImage(item.image[0].id) for example.
<a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="changeImage(123)">Test</a>

And the method currently:
<script>
    function changeImage(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
</script>


Don't use an a element for such thing but a button. Wrap the function into some script setup or otherwise add it to a methods object. Give a read to the docs on the listeners to see some code examples. If it still does not work please use Vue's playground with a [repro].

you can write like this if you want use a element:
<script setup>
function handleClick(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
</script>

<template>
 <a @click.prevent="handleClick(123)">Test</a>
</template>

another way:
Don't use the a element you can use another element like the button element  and click on it like this:
<script setup>
function callMe(e){
  console.log(e)
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="changeImage(123)">test</button>
</template>


@click.prevent

@imhvost just no. Why recommending to use a hack on top of a bad practice? Looks quite unnecessary.

@kissu What hack are we talking about? I'm just reminding the answerer about Event Modifiers in Vue.js!

@imhvost You are right I forgot that I changed it to @click.prevent thanks

@imhvost having <a> + .prevent in the docs does not mean that this is the way to go. It was more illustrative than the way to go for any UI interaction. Weird advice.

I recommend not using the <a> element from a semantic point of view but rather <button>.
Also, I am not sure how javascript:void(0) behaves on SSR.
Lastly, this kind of code is not very good in terms of UX because it forces ther user into not being able to open it in a new tab easily.
Overall, please use a button this is what it is used for and it follows the basics of accessibility.
<script setup>
function callMe(e){
  console.log(e)
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="callMe('123')">click me</button>
</template>

Here is a working playground

Please post some actual code and not just a link. ))

You have a problem with something else because it works: Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const image = ref(1);

const changeImage = (number) => image.value = number
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ image }}
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="changeImage(123)">image = 123</a>
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="changeImage(image + 1)">image++</a>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
</style>


Please post some actual code and not just a link.

OK. Added the code. So maybe you'll do just that in your reply before you ask me?

Can you read things actually? Probably missed something here.
